# React uncaught type error: Cannot read properties of undefined reading params

Tags: reactjs, redux, parameters

[image]
[image]

[image]

My Page is showing blank. please help me to fix this problem

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add your code as text.

Comment: Please don't use comments to add code. [Edit] your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You already imported `useParams` from `react-router-dom`, so you need to add

```
const { nftId } = useParams();
```

instead of using `match.params.nftId`

Then you can put a condition like `if (nftId) { your code here }`

Comment: thank you for your comment. please can you help me get all the exact right codes? I am  so confused here

Comment: add the line I put above your useState lines, and what is the error you're getting now ?